# Complex Number Template Classes

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
#ifndef COMPLEXNUMBER_H
#define COMPLEXNUMBER_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ComplexNumber
{

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const ComplexNumber&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, ComplexNumber&);
public:

    void setComplexNumber(const T&, const T&);
    T getComplexNumber(T&, T&) const;
    ComplexNumber();
    ComplexNumber(T real , T imaginary);
    T operator+(const ComplexNumber&)const;
    T operator-(const ComplexNumber&)const;
    T operator*(const ComplexNumber&)const;
    T operator/(const ComplexNumber&)const;
    T& operator=(const ComplexNumber&);
    bool operator==(const ComplexNumber&) const;
    bool operator!=(const ComplexNumber&) const;

private:

    T realnumber;
    T imaginarynumber;
};

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const ComplexNumber<T>& complex)
{

    out<<complex.realnumber;
    out<<"+";
    out<<complex.imaginarynumber;
    out<<"i";
    return out;
}

template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream& in, ComplexNumber<T>& complex)
{
    char ch;
    in>>complex.realnumber;
    in>>complex.imaginarynumber;
    in>>ch;
    return in;
}

template <class T>
T& ComplexNumber<T>::operator=(const ComplexNumber& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        realnumber = other.realnumber;
        imaginarynumber = other.imaginarynumber;
    }

    return  *this;
}

template <class T>
bool ComplexNumber<T>::operator ==(const ComplexNumber& other) const
{
    return (realnumber == other.realnumber && imaginarynumber == other.imaginarynumber);
}

template<class T>
bool ComplexNumber<T>::operator !=(const ComplexNumber& other) const
{
    return (realnumber != other.realnumber && imaginarynumber != other.imaginarynumber);
}


//Default Constructor
template<class T>
ComplexNumber<T>::ComplexNumber()
{
    realnumber = 0.0;
    imaginarynumber = 0.0;
}


//Constructor which takes in two arguments
template<class T>
ComplexNumber<T>::ComplexNumber(const T real,const T imaginary)
{
    realnumber = real;
    imaginarynumber = imaginary;
}

template<class T>
void ComplexNumber<T>::setComplexNumber(const T& real, const T& imaginary)
{
    realnumber = real;
    imaginarynumber = imaginary;
}

//Overloaded Addition Operator
template<class T>
T ComplexNumber<T>::operator +(const ComplexNumber& other) const
{
    ComplexNumber<T>temp;
    temp.realnumber = realnumber + other.realnumber;
    temp.imaginarynumber = imaginarynumber + other.imaginarynumber;
    return ComplexNumber;
}

//Overloaded subtraction operator
template<class T>
T ComplexNumber<T>::operator -(const ComplexNumber& other) const
{
    ComplexNumber<T> temp;
    temp.realnumber = realnumber - other.realnumber;
    temp.imaginarynumber = imaginarynumber - other.imaginarynumber;
    return temp;
}

//Overloaded multiplication operator
template<class T>
T ComplexNumber<T> ::operator *(const ComplexNumber& other)const
{
    ComplexNumber<T> temp;
    temp.realnumber = (realnumber * other.realnumber) - (imaginarynumber * other.imaginarynumber);
    temp.imaginarynumber = (realnumber * other.imaginarynumber) + (imaginarynumber * other.realnumber); 
    return temp;
}

//Overloaded division operator
template<class T>
T ComplexNumber<T> ::operator/(const ComplexNumber& other)const
{
    ComplexNumber<T> temp;  
    temp.realnumber = ((realnumber * other.realnumber) + (imaginarynumber * other.imaginarynumber))/((pow(other.realnumber,2.0))+(pow(other.imaginarynumber,2.0)));
    temp.imaginarynumber = ((other.realnumber * imaginarynumber) - (realnumber * other.imaginarynumber))/((pow(other.realnumber,2.0))+(pow(other.imaginarynumber,2.0))); 
    return temp;
}


#endif
```

I get a problem saying that my addition, subtraction, multiplication and division operator cannot convert from ComplexNumber to double or any other data type that I want to. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Because in the main, the user needs to be able to use any kind of data type that the user wants. Hence, I am using T.

Comment: I tried changing my private members to doubles but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer what if (for some reason) the OP wanted a `ComplexNumber<long double>`? Or Gaussian integers? Storing a private `T` is just fine IMO.

Comment: Don't put `using namespace` in header files.

Comment: You're aware of `#include <complex>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Overloaded Addition Operator
template<class T>
T ComplexNumber<T>::operator +(const ComplexNumber& other) const
{
    ComplexNumber<T>temp;
    temp.realnumber = realnumber + other.realnumber;
    temp.imaginarynumber = imaginarynumber + other.imaginarynumber;
    return ComplexNumber;
}
```

I need to

```
return temp;
```

here to get this to compile. Is that what you're asking about?

Also, in that case, you probably want the method to return `ComplexNumber<T>`, not `T`. That's probably the conversion issue you're seeing. It's trying to convert `ComplexNumber<T>` to `T` to return. And `T` is double in whatever example you're running I guess.

A few other issues. The friend declaration needs to be a template. And some other things. But here's a functional version. At least it works for me. It needs the other operators added back in.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ComplexNumber
{
public:
    ComplexNumber();
    ComplexNumber(T real , T imaginary);
    ComplexNumber<T> operator+(const ComplexNumber<T>&)const;

    template <class U> 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const ComplexNumber<U>&);

private:
    T realnumber;
    T imaginarynumber;
};

//Default Constructor
template<class T>
ComplexNumber<T>::ComplexNumber()
{
    realnumber = 0.0;
    imaginarynumber = 0.0;
}


//Constructor which takes in two arguments
template<class T>
ComplexNumber<T>::ComplexNumber(const T real,const T imaginary)
{
    realnumber = real;
    imaginarynumber = imaginary;
}

//Overloaded Addition Operator
template<class T>
ComplexNumber<T> ComplexNumber<T>::operator +(const ComplexNumber<T>& other) const
{
    ComplexNumber<T> temp;
    temp.realnumber = realnumber + other.realnumber;
    temp.imaginarynumber = imaginarynumber + other.imaginarynumber;
    return temp;
}

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const ComplexNumber<T>& complex)
{
    out<<complex.realnumber;
    out<<"+";
    out<<complex.imaginarynumber;
    out<<"i";
    return out;
}

int main(){
  ComplexNumber<double> cn1(1,1);
  ComplexNumber<double> cn2(1,1);
  ComplexNumber<double> cn3 = cn1+cn2;
  cout<<cn3<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried returning temp but it still does not work. My TA told me "Error is because you return a ComplexNumber<T> in the functions but the declarations say it will return "T", in this case a double." I do not really understand what he means when he says that and I cannot contact him now. If you could explain that line to me by being a bit more specific, that would really help. Thanks

Comment: Yeah ok. Your addition methods are returning T. They need to return ComplexNumber<T>

Comment: I tried returning ComplexNumber<T>. The compiler is now telling me "illegal use of this type as an expression". I am wondering if my implementation of class template with overloaded operators is wrong in some way.

Comment: @user5697099: Not `return ComplexNumber<T>`. You want to `return temp;`. But you need change the return type of the function  to `ComplexNumber<T>`.

Comment: I am sorry but can you please write down a single line and tell me what you mean. I am new to this and so I am having a tough time grabbing the idea.

Comment: @user5697099: The return statement needs to be `return temp;`. The return type of the function needs to be `ComplexNumber<T>`.

Comment: There were some other issues. I gave you an functioning example that works for me above.----^

Answer (score 0):

The overloaded operator+ is returning an item by value so this will work. The key to remember is that you cannot return an address. For example, say the overload was written as

```
ComplexNumber<T> &ComplexNumber<T>::operator +(const ComplexNumber<T>& other) const...
```

You would then be returning a pointer to something that will be deleted in the garbage collector. I have yet to find an easy-to-explain way to return a pointer for this kind of operator that needs two parameters (also -, *, ? etc.). Love to hear how to do that particularly when separating into a .h and .cpp file to hide the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T=int>    // LINE-1
class mytype {
    T a, b;
public:
    mytype(T _a, T _b) : a(_a), b(_b) { }
 
 mytype<T> operator + (   mytype<T> & b) //LINE 2
{
  mytype<T> c(0,0);
  c.a = a + b.a;
  c.b = this->b + b.b;
  return(c);   // LINE 3
}
    void show() {
        cout << a << ", " << b << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    int i1=10, i2=20, i3=30, i4=40;
   // cin >> i1 >> i2 >> i3 >> i4;

    mytype<> obj1(i1, i2);
    mytype<> obj2(i3, i4);
    mytype<> obj3 = obj1 + obj2;

    double d1=10.1, d2=20.2, d3=30.3, d4=40.4;
  //  cin >> d1 >> d2 >> d3 >> d4;

    mytype<double> obj4(d1, d2);
    mytype<double> obj5(d3, d4);
    mytype<double> obj6 = obj4 + obj5;

    obj3.show();
    obj6.show();`enter code here`

    return 0;
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: The answer will be more useful if it includes not only the code but also a detailed description of the problem solution.